# How do I send the form for crdt-share-buffer?

Tags: emacs

I can't see how I can send the form when starting a new nrdt.el share.
It says that I should press RET, but pressing enter in the gui or terminal doesn't work.
Any help?

Edit: I'm new to emacs and I just don't know how to send a form, and I don't know how it's actually named, which is why I couldn't find anything googling.

I'm using doom emacs with a client-daemon configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I found why it wasn't working: Doom Emacs rebinds exit-recursive-edit to C-M-c (which you have to use to send the form).

Comment: `C-M-c` is a *standard* binding for `exit-recursive-edit` (i.e. not a Doom thing).  What had caused you to think it was something different?

Comment: @phils I am new to emacs, so I just didn't know it.

Comment: Interestingly I see `crdt-read-settings-map` binds `RET` to `exit-recursive-edit` so it *does* sound like there's something unexpected going on.  What does `C-h k RET` tell you in that situation?  (n.b. I don't use this library; I just took a look out of interest, so I don't know if that keymap is expected to be active in your situation or not.)